# Whitelist gitlab webhooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-vpc

I'm using gitlab.com as my repository and I'm hosting my own gitlab runner in my own VPC in AWS. This is working fine however, I would like to add some additional layer of security by tightening my NACL to only allow the gitlab.com SaaS to reach my VPC.

Their own [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ip-range) states that it should work and list a few ip ranges used by them and cloudflare. However, it still isn't working. It is obvious that it is the NACL because simply adding `0.0.0.0/0` as and allow in the inbound makes the runner job complete as intended. However, removing `0.0.0.0/0` and only allowing the ip's listed below makes the gitlab job get stuck and it behaves as if no connection is established.

```
34.74.226.0/24
34.74.90.64/28

173.245.48.0/20
103.21.244.0/22
103.22.200.0/22
103.31.4.0/22
141.101.64.0/18
108.162.192.0/18
190.93.240.0/20
188.114.96.0/20
197.234.240.0/22
198.41.128.0/17
162.158.0.0/15
104.16.0.0/13
104.24.0.0/14
172.64.0.0/13
131.0.72.0/22

2400:cb00::/32
2606:4700::/32
2803:f800::/32
2405:b500::/32
2405:8100::/32
2a06:98c0::/29
2c0f:f248::/32
```

After having added all these ranges to my NACL as inbound rules. It still is unable to connect without allowing `0.0.0.0/0`.

**Additional information**

Here is an overview of my VPC setup:

The public subnet NACL has all the ips listed above as allowed, on all ports for all protocols on inbound connections. The outbound is currently set as 0.0.0.0/0.

The private subnet allows 0.0.0.0/0 for both inbound and outbound.

[image: VPC config]

Comment: Is GitLab not able to connect to your runner at all? How are you determining this? What kind of error message are you getting and where?
If the job starts but a deploy (etc.) fails, then is the job using the shared runner instead of your own? Have you disabled shared runners?

Comment: The job gets stuck as if connection is not going through. It becomes very obvious that its the NACL because if I just add the incoming rule 0.0.0.0/0 as allow then the connection gets established and the job runs as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have solved the issue. The problem was that I had not added an allow in the NACL for local connections. Hence the private subnet was unable to connect to the NAT gateway.